# How to get individual value out of an array in this scenario?

Tags: php, arrays

So I am working with a wordpress plugin, but this is more a general php question. The `add_date` below is an array. I would like to `echo` one  value in the array. The code below doesn't seem to be working. Could someone help please? It would be appreciated!

```
if( have_rows('add_date') ) {
echo $add_date[1];
}
```

Comment: Hello Leona, what kind of error are you getting? What does the `have_rows`  function do? Is `add_date` the array or an index, the `if` argument is confusing. It seems as if you are trying to check an array (not `$add_date`) if the index `add_date` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes does what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$count = 0;
$your_repeater = get_field('add_date');
if($your_repeater){
   while( have_rows('add_date') ): the_row();
   $count++;
   $my_field = get_sub_field('course_date');
   if ($count == 1) {
      echo '<div class="image1">'.$my_field.'</div>';
   }
   if ($count == 2) {
      echo '<div class="image2">'.$my_field.'</div>';
   }
   if ($count == 3) {
      echo '<div class="image3">'.$my_field.'</div>';
   }
   if ($count == 4) {
      echo '<div class="image4">'.$my_field.'</div>';
   }
   if ($count == 5) {
      echo '<div class="image5">'.$my_field.'</div>';
   }
endwhile;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

echo $add_date[0];

PHP arrays are 0-based, so the first value is at 0, not 1

Comment: Sorry, I explained my questions poorly. It won't echo values 1,2, or 3 . I just want to get one value. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand what you want then, because "echo $add_date[0];"  would just give you the first value.  What is your input and what do you want as your output?

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided you with more information to answer the question. I didn't realize this. I have provided the answer now. Thanks for the help!